# How to Implement Header and Sidebar with React-Router

Tags: react-router-v4

I am new with React Router and I want implement the following:

```
// if the user is connected 
<div>
   <header/>
   <sidebar/>
   <content/>
   <footer/>
</div>
// else
<login/>
```

I am using React-Router v4.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in the main component and so create directly in the render function a if/else condition.

```
render(){

   if (this.state.logged === true{
        <YOUR CONTENT WITH SIDEBAR...>
   }else{
        <LoginComponent>
   }
}
```

And so, just change the state of the main component to access the component you want.

React routeur is here to manage your url in the app and show the good component depending of the url. But if you put your code directly in the component with base router code you can manage your loggin